# Looking for sql parametrized queries reference

Tags: sql, sqlite

We’ve decided to store sql parametrized queries text in xml files. For this project we use SQLite with C# code (http://system.data.sqlite.org/) but miss some base information reference about how flexible the parametrized queries are, especially in standard SQL first, and for this DB engine too. It’s undoubtable variables are parametrizable (value for where A = …), that table names aren’t, but we’re not totally sure about column names (select xxx from mytable).
Thank you for helping me to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all SQL engines, and SQLite is no exception, table and column names cannot be parametrized.

This is because parametrized queries most of the time are precompiled, and in order for precompilation to work, SQL engine needs to create query plans - which tables to join using which columns, and which indexes to use. If table and column names were unknown at this stage, pre-compilation would not be possible. This is why only values for constraints (like in WHERE) are allowed to be parametrized (using `?`, `$1` or `:name` syntax, depending on SQL engine support).